# How do I know if my ship has a recharging station?

Tags: starfinder, starship

> "At the GM’s discretion, **some larger starships might have onboard
> recharging stations.** These might offer recharging at low or no cost,
> but they typically take 1 minute per charge to recharge a battery or
> power cell."

— Core Rule Book p234

Our group wants to have a Starship - either a stock build or a custom build - that has one of these "onboard recharging stations" but I could not locate such rules in the Ship Builder rules of the Core Rule Book, nor in the Starship Operations Manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The GM Decides

You have already found the relevant rules, no need to keep searching. The GM has the discretion to say whether a ship has a charging station. The only way for you to know whether your ship does is to ask your GM.

Comment: I wonder if Paizo realizes not every GM is going to say yes.

Comment: @Tristian In the SF games I have played, it was normal to recharge batteries in between adventures or in "safe ports". It usually didn't happen in adventures. Sure a charging  station on-board would be convenient, but it isn't a practical requirement.